# Understanding procedures in Snowflake (javascript)

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I came through lately following line of code while analyzing 3rd party data script.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WH.SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_NAME(DATE_OF_LOAD STRING) --input which will be binded later
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE javascript
  AS $$

   var drop_table = `drop table if exists TABLE_NAME;`; 
   var stmt_drop_table = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: drop_table} );
   var incremental_data =
     `CREATE TABLE AS <many arguments>

      WHERE P.CZAS_MODYF_SF >= :1 --this is where biding of DATE_OF_LOAD occurs)

   SELECT *, HASH(*) HASH FROM (
                             SELECT <arguments>
                            FROM CTE) q; `;

   var stmt_incremental_data = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: incremental_data,binds: [DATE_OF_LOAD ].map(function(x){return x === undefined ? null : x}) } );

   try {

    stmt_drop_table.execute();  
    stmt_incremental_data.execute(); 
    rtr = "Success!";
    return rtr;
    }

   catch (err) {

       return "Failed: " + err;
}  
$$
;
```

Entire challenge I have is with:

`var stmt_incremental_data = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: incremental_data,binds: [DATE_OF_LOAD ].map(function(x){return x === undefined ? null : x}) } )`.

`object`.`method` part is clear. Same for `binds`. Code after `binds` is my issue here.

Another topic: Snowflake interpretes method's parameters as a JSON. Does it mean that `bind` value can be extended by assigning JS code?
I'll be greatly thankful for help and explanation.

Comment: if [DATE_OF_LOAD] is undefined it will replace it with null, otherwise it will use whatever value is stored in DATE_OF_LOAD. That is because SQL does not know how to handle undefined.

Comment: @GabrielDurac I don't understand why you did not post it as answer. If you post it as answer, it can be selected as correct, and people looking for answer can be sure that it's the solution. Comments should be used for asking additional questions to clarify the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I did not post this as an answer initially is that JavaScript is not my area of expertise. I did dabble in it for a few months.

But in order to understand what is going on with:

```
[DATE_OF_LOAD ].map(function(x){return x === undefined ? null : x})
```

You need to break it down:

```
 x === undefined ? null : x
```

This is called an [elvis operator](https://medium.com/@krzakmarek88/optional-chaining-aka-elvis-operator-in-javascript-dc7f2bea2076) and is the equivalent of :

```
if (x === undefined) 
{ 
  return null
} else { 
  return x 
}
```

Now that we know what the function does, we need to understand the [map](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/the-javascript-array-map-method-44m0) method. But in short it creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So the simple answer copied from my comment is:
if DATE_OF_LOAD is undefined it will replace it with null, otherwise it will use whatever value is stored in DATE_OF_LOAD. That is because SQL does not know how to handle undefined. 
 But here is the reasoning for my answer.